# How can i get all wine list api?

Tags: android, api, retrofit2

I want to integrate all the wine list screen.

I am found this [link](https://api.wine.com/) but i dont understand how can i call the apis.

What is the best way to achieve the list?

Answer (score 0):

You could/should use [retrofit2](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for that

Your call then would look something like this:

```
GET("/api/beta2/service.svc/format/resource")
Call<ResponseBody> makeMyCall(@Query("apikey") key, /** ... parameters ... **/)
```

Comment: ok thank you for give me reply but i want to know which parameter i want to pass into this link.

Comment: @nidhi93 the api is documented in their site.https://api.wine.com/wiki
what parameter you need depends on what you want to do...